# Python2.7 to Python3 Ubuntu switch

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to install graph tool on ubuntu. 
Therefore I want to make the default version of python to 3.7 instead of 2.7 because my compiler give me the error, that the python interpreter is to old to run the configure.

So do u know an solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't mess with the version `python` points to. Important tools on your system might expect it to be Python 2. Worst case would be a hard to repair broken system. If you need `python` to point to version 3, use a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: If you copy the error message will be easier to find someone who can help you.

Comment: How are you installing it? You can do it via pip (it’s on PyPA). Just use pip3 or python3 -m pip install.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute `Python3` when you run the `python` command, the easiest way to do it is create an alias like this:

```
alias python=python3
```

But you don't need to mess with it, maybe you can launch the configurations and run programs with `python3` command instead of `python`.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 file.py`

Or add `#!/usr/bin/python3` to the first line of your code to automatically run it with python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend not using aliases nor changing defaults. Those things have a way of coming back to bite you later on.

By your description, you said that the tool said the interpreter was too old. I'll guess that it needs a python3 interpreter. So what you should do is a simple `sudo apt install python3` and use `python3` instead of `python` when running the code from the terminal.

Example:

Instead of `python manage.py runserver`

Do... `python3 manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

1. List all the installed versions of Python 3: `ls /usr/bin/python3*`
2. Add Python 3.7 to the alternatives list and change its priority: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1`
3. Change the default version of Python by using following command:

   `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Type the number of the version you wish to set as default and confirm with enter.

4. Double check, that the change was successfully introduced by: `python -V`